# Ruby: can I avoid lots of escaping in a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping

Lets say I want to match against CVS comments like:

```
//     $Source$
```

My regex currently looks like this:

```
if ( /^\/\/\s*\$Source\$/ =~ line)
```

Which works, but I'm left wondering -- is there a prettier way to write this?

Comment: `%r{//\s*$Source\$}`?

Comment: While the answer may indeed be the same, I would argue that my question is not phrased in php terms, meaning it will be much more useful to those of us who don't use php.  I don't know if that argues against flagging it as duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `%r` syntax:

```
if ( %r{//\s*\$Source\$} =~ line)
             ^^ I'm not sure whether ruby would allow unescaped `$` here or not
```

Comment: The escaping seems to be necessary to get a correct match, but still, solves my problem, thanks.